# Heroku application error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, crash

My app stopped working out the of the blue while I was using it, with the error message:

"An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.

If you are the application owner, check your logs for details."

My logs file is below, and I'm suspecting this is a problem at the heroku end, but it has persisted for over half an hour now.

```
2013-06-02T16:42:00.904689+00:00 app[web.1]: 0
2013-06-02T16:42:00.904689+00:00 app[web.1]: 0
2013-06-02T16:42:00.904689+00:00 app[web.1]: 0
2013-06-02T16:42:00.903915+00:00 app[web.1]: 0
2013-06-02T16:42:00.904307+00:00 app[web.1]: 0
2013-06-02T16:42:00.904307+00:00 app[web.1]: 0
2013-06-02T16:42:00.905033+00:00 app[web.1]: 0
2013-06-02T16:42:00.905213+00:00 app[web.1]: 0
2013-06-02T16:42:00.905213+00:00 app[web.1]: 0
2013-06-02T16:42:00.905213+00:00 app[web.1]: 0
2013-06-02T16:42:00.905213+00:00 app[web.1]: 0
2013-06-02T16:42:00.905213+00:00 app[web.1]: 0
2013-06-02T16:42:00.905213+00:00 app[web.1]: 0
2013-06-02T16:42:00.905403+00:00 app[web.1]: 0
2013-06-02T16:42:00.904689+00:00 app[web.1]: 0
2013-06-02T16:42:00.904863+00:00 app[web.1]: 0
```

Comment: Should have asked a question! My question is: what could be the cause of this. Is it me or heroku?

Comment: Output of `heroku logs` is the samething posted above?

Comment: Yes, that is what heroku logs gave me.

Comment: https://status.heroku.com/ is showing no known issues, so if it is a heroku issue, they don't know about it.

Comment: Fixed it. heroku restart had no effect, but going into maintenance mode and coming out again did the trick.